# How to correctly call up the toggle state from sessionstorage?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, session-storage

I've written a feature that adds class changing the look of the site (something similar to dark mode). I managed to save its status to sessionStorage. When you click the button, the state is activated and saved when refreshing the page. The problem occurs when I turn off the state, then coming to other subpages dark mode is immediately activated. I am trying to figure out what is wrong here. Maybe one of you will have some tips for me. Thank you in advance for all your help.

JQuery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var state = localStorage.getItem("toggleState");
    if(state == "true"){
        $('*').not('div.excluded *').toggleClass("white-contrast");             
        $('header, footer').toggleClass("white-contrast-border");
        $('img, div.excluded').toggleClass("background-overlay");
    }

    $('#white-contrast').click(function(){
        $('*').not('div.excluded *').toggleClass("white-contrast");             
        $('header, footer').toggleClass("white-contrast-border");
        $('img, div.excluded').toggleClass("background-overlay");
        localStorage.setItem("toggleState","true");
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<button id="white-contrast" type="button"></button>
```